# What does the treemp function do, here?

Tags: haskell, tree

What does the treemp function does, here? What do the input and output correspond to?

```hs
import Data.Word
import Data.Char
import Data.List


import System.Environment

data Tree a = Leaf a | Root a [Tree a] deriving (Eq, Show)

treemp f (Leaf a) = Leaf $ f a
treemp f (Root a ts) = Root (f a) $ map (treemp f) ts


t0 = Root 0 [t1,t2,t3,t4,t5]

t1 = Leaf 1

t2 = Root 2 [Leaf 6, Leaf 7, Root 11 [Leaf 12, Leaf 13]]

t3 = Root 3 [Leaf 8, Leaf 9]

t4 = Root 4 [Leaf 10]

t5 = Leaf 5
```

Comment: `treemp :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b`. It's essentially the implementation of `fmap` that corresponds to your `Tree` type. In other words, `treemp` is to `Tree` what `map` is to lists.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by looking at the type.

```
treemp :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
```

So `treemp f` lifts the function `f` over `Tree`s. It's analogous to `map` for lists and is `fmap` for this `Tree a` type.

How did I work out the type? Let's look at the first case:

```
treemp f (Leaf a) = Leaf $ f a
```

We know `(Leaf a)` must have type `Tree a`. And we know that because the `Leaf` constructor is applied to an argument the return type must be a `Tree b`. Further, we know that `f` must be a function that can take an `a` as an argument and it's return type must match `b`. So `f :: a -> b`. We can plug these pieces back together and get back to the type I put up above. The type matches the type of `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` so we know it must lift the function over the `Tree a` type.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like an `fmap` definition for `Tree`. Given an `f :: a -> b`, it would apply `f` to every `a` in a `Tree a` (in the `Leaf` and `Root`, and recursively to each `Tree` in `Root`), returning a `Tree b`